# Accessing SSH server outside the local network

Tags: server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I have an SSH server set up within my university premises which cannot be accessed from outside the network of university.

I want to be able to access it from my home WI-FI network. **Probably it is possible through OpenVPN but I cannot figure out how to set it up to access the server.** I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Does the openvpn server exist in university network?

Comment: @KrzysztofSawicki no it does not

Comment: If there\s no OpenVPN server in the network that has access to the "SSH server" then you will not achieve this using OpenVPN. Maybe your university has any other VPN for students?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about the VPN client that my university offers for outside access (CISCO VPN) and from there onwards it was easy to access the SSH server.